# How to avoid redirection to front page in photo gallery using Views

Tags: 6, javascript, rating

I'm using Drupal 6 Fivestar, voting API,voting api_autoremove modules for voting system.There is a Photo gallery in my site where the users can vote for their desired picture.I brought the pictures through views and which is also using the pager(currently it has 1 to 5 pages).

If an user votes for an image in third page(for example i'm saying third page, it may be any inner page that is not the first page),it saves the vote and it is redirected to the first page.But i wanna make the user to stay in the same page ie the third page in this case(in whichever the page they are being voted).

I searched for a very long time but didn't find out any solutions.Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any one know this? if yes please help me.